# How to handle big numbers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to convert all my numbers to 4 fixed decimal points for that I am using toFixed()

```
 (1456.454534).toFixed()
```

But in my case I do have some number which are crossing the limit of MAX_SAFE_INTEGER like

```
11324237868788877767787.676886
```

In that case if I am using toFixed() it results into loss of precision.How can I handle this number?

Comment: Turn it into a string, then use your own parser or a library that handles it, probably

Comment: Easiest way is to store and handle it as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your JS environment and compatibility requirements, you may have the new BigInt type available.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

If using only the latest and greatest isn't an option, there is at least one [polyfill library](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/) out there

... or sure, you could represent it as a string as some commenters suggest, but it's awkward to do math with those strings.